# Listado de Registros en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

resulta que estoy ingresando datos a un sistema de información que estoy realizando. La idea es que me muestre los datos a través de un listado, sin embargo me arroja los siguientes errores:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Papeleria2\index.php on
>   line 41 Notice: Undefined index: name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Papeleria2\index.php on line 42 Notice: Undefined
>   index: cedula in C:\xampp\htdocs\Papeleria2\index.php on line 43
>   Notice: Undefined index: direccion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Papeleria2\index.php on line 44 Notice: Undefined
>   index: telefono in C:\xampp\htdocs\Papeleria2\index.php on line 45
>   Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\Papeleria2\index.php
>   on line 46

Este es el código fuente para index.php

```
<?php
  require 'conexion.php';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
?>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Papelería</title>
</head>
</html>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2 style="text-align:center">Papelería</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <a href="NuevoCliente.php" class="button">Nuevo Registro</a>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row table-responsive">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Cedula</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          { ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['cedula']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['direccion']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['telefono']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Estoy a la espera de una posible solución al problema. Gracias.

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que o tu query falla o la tabla no tiene esos campos

Comment: como estan definidos los cmapos en la BD?

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada verificar si tu consulta no está fallando haciendo un `var_dump()` y para imprimir tus datos en la tabla basta con hacer un `foreach()` y recorrer el array asociativo que obtuvimos utilizando `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

**Código:**

```
<?php
  require 'conexion.php';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Papelería</title>
</head>
</html>
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2 style="text-align:center">Papelería</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <a href="NuevoCliente.php" class="button">Nuevo Registro</a>
    </div><br>
    <div class="row table-responsive">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Cedula</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php 
            $rows = $result->mysqli_fetch_assoc();
            foreach($rows as $row){ ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['cedula']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['direccion']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['telefono']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```